# database not updating for some reason

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This sql query is not updating the database, instead returning error. Any suggestions?

```
                    PreparedStatement ps10 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip SET hours_worked = (SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM payroll_system.monthly_timesheet WHERE employeeID=?) WHERE employeeID=?");
                    ps10.setString(1, employee_id);
                    ps10.setString(2, employee_id);
                    ps10.executeUpdate();
```

monthly_timesheet table:

[image]

payslip table:

[image]

Comment: That `INSERT` statement is simply incorrect. Your `WHERE` clause has to be _after_ your `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert don't have where clause  
"INSERT INTO payroll_system.payslip(expense_claims) 
 WHERE employeeID=? 
 SELECT SUM(expense) FROM payroll_system.expense_master"
```

eventually you are looking  for update?

or use

```
     "INSERT INTO payroll_system.payslip(expense_claims) 
      SELECT SUM(expense) FROM payroll_system.expense_mast"
```

for update

```
 PreparedStatement ps9 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip 
     SET expense_claims = (SELECT SUM(Expense) 
     FROM payroll_system.expense_master 
     WHERE employeeID=?) WHERE employeeID=?");

     ps9.setString(1, employee_id);
     ps9.setString(2, employee_id);
     ps9.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Could you show how to do it with an update please? :) using where clause

Comment: Hmm, this didn't quite work. It set every row in expense_claims to the sum of all rows in the expense_master table. Now expense_claims column is all 959.

Comment: have you assigne a prper value to '?'  for employedID ?? .. or ezplain better your query .. result